# How to use the blur event on text

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to use the `blur` event on a text instead of an input? If so, how do I achieve that using vanilla JavaScript? I've searched a lot but I can't find the answer I'm looking for.

Comment: blur is triggered when focus leaves an input element. how would focus be on a text element? Can you pls update your question with an example and your attempt?

Comment: It's been answered, I have used the same method but without the tabindex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible if you add a `tabindex` to the text element

```js
var p = document.getElementById("test");

p.addEventListener("focus", function(e) {
  e.target.style.color = "red";  
});

p.addEventListener("blur", function(e) {
  e.target.style.color = "";  
});
```

```html
<p id="test" tabindex="0">Test</p>
```

Comment: If that answers your question you should mark it as accepted (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).